# How does count work in Ruby when a string is set as the parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How does count work in this code:

```
name= "abcdef"
puts name.count("aeiou")
puts name.count("^aeiou")
```

Does it count for the occurrences of "a", "e", "i", "o" and "u"?

If yes, how can I count the occurrences of "aeiou" as a single string?

Does the negation include counting for 'spaces'? Why/why not?

Comment: Link to documentatIon: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-count

Comment: This is covered in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, `name.count("aeiou")` will return any instances of any characters in name that match "a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u".  If you want to count as a string you'd use `scan` like:

```
name.scan(/aeiou/).count
```

`count` also includes whitespaces.

Comment: Anytime.  If that's all you need mark it correct for others to reference.

Comment: Don't rush to accept answers. SO is a global site, and it takes many hours for everyone to see and formulate good answers. Premature selection discourages others from answering, which potentially hurts you, and others who search for similar solutions in the future. Remember, SO isn't about you getting an answer only, it's about documenting programming problems and their solutions for others in the future, so the better the question, and the attending solutions, the better for everyone.

Comment: If it's about documenting programming problems and solutions, how does my selection discourage others from answering?